# Video clarity missing in my ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Tags: 14.04, apt

Recently i installed ubuntu 14.04(32bit) in my system,
when i play the videos which are already stored in my system are not playing with a clarity, playing something like 3gp videos. But when i play youtube videos there is a good clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Please run the video in totem player by installing it

```
sudo apt-get install totem
```

If it was installed, try re-installing the player

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall totem
```